# Import does not work redmine_loader plugin. Does not work "update exists"

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I installed on Redmine redmine_loader plugin to import projects from MSProject in Redmine.

Unfortunately function  "update exists" does not work.

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                2.5.1.stable.13174
  Ruby version                   2.0.0-p481 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  3.2.18
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
SCM:
  Subversion                     1.8.8
  Git                            1.9.1
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  redmine_loader                 0.3b
  redmine_omniauth_google        0.0.1
```

How to solve the problem?

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

~ Redmine loader has invalid default settings so you get these errors. You need to update your plugin's init.rb with this content: https://gist.github.com/noma4i/9a3cd7c9771201bb9e29

Actually problem is in **settings** section. You need this part to fix your issue:

```
settings default: {
    tracker_alias: 'Tracker',
    redmine_id_alias: 'RID',
    redmine_status_alias: 'RSTATUS',
    export: {
      sync_versions: false,
      ignore_fields: {
        description: false,
        priority: false,
        done_ratio: false,
        estimated_hours: false,
        spent_hours: false
      }
    },
    import: {
      is_private_by_default: false,
      instant_import_tasks: 10,
      sync_versions: false,
      ignore_fields: {
        description: false,
        priority: false,
        done_ratio: false,
        estimated_hours: false,
        spent_hours: false
      }
    },
  }, partial: 'settings/loader_settings'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
Unfortunately, the plugin source code is identical to yours. The problem remains. BUT, if you remove the line in 29 [link](https://github.com/m0n9oose/redmine_loader/blob/master/lib/import.rb) # + '_imported' # Max length of this field is 255 ,  then the import works, but there is a new problem - not updated the old issues, and added as new.

Comment: As I see there is definition of self.import_tasks in that file and it is set to update_existing=false by default. Change it to update_existing=false and will try to update existing and fallback to Issue.new.